# Apple IAP question for deprecated /verifyResponse

Tags: node.js, go, in-app-purchase, backend

I'm working on an iOS app and building its backend using node.js. I've come across an issue, and I'm hoping some of you might be able to help me out. It seems that the "/verifyResponse" method I used to rely on has been deprecated. In the past, I would receive a receipt on the backend and extract the originalTransactionId using /verifyResponse.

This information would then be stored in the database, and later on, I'd complete the process by populating the necessary data through Apple Server Notification while ensuring its accuracy.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not entirely sure how to proceed with this workflow anymore. Despite reading the documentation and watching Apple's videos, I keep seeing references to /verifyResponse. Could anyone provide guidance on how to correctly implement this flow without using /verifyResponse? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

I watched video from apple and read apple documentation, and i dont understand how to do w/o /verifyReceipt

Comment: Sorry this does not answer your question. I have the exact same problem that I need to solve this very weekend. Currently I am writing logic based on the source code of https://github.com/apple/app-store-server-library-node, but when I enter a base64 string starting with MII sent from my app, I am not able to get the same amount of information in json as in the verifyReceipt response.